# Euler discretization

Tags: options, option-pricing, monte-carlo

I have been told that the Euler discretisation is exact for the GBM process.Is it true and how can I proof this?  This would mean, for a GBM process, if I am increasing my discretisation step, the value is unaffected. However, in many application, the error for discretisation of GBM decreases with increasing steps. What is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is exact if you shift to log coordinates first. In that case, you are discretising Brownian motion with drift i.e.
$$
d\log S_t = (\mu-0.5\sigma^2 )dt + \sigma dW_t
$$

It is definitely not exact in the original coordinates, since the probability of going negative is positive for this discretization.